# Conditionally Calling Terraform Resource Based on The Module's Variable

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform

Say that I have two modules that require the same source (**append_only_history_bq_tables**). Their difference is only the **from_dwh_core** variable which the default set to **false**

```
module "dwh_core_append_only_history_tables" {
  source            = "../append_only_history_bq_tables"
  gcp_project       = var.gcp_project
  bq_location       = var.bq_location
  dataset_id        = google_bigquery_dataset.jago_pagerduty.dataset_id
  module_base_path  = path.module
  tables = {
    "list_incident"             = { "business_key_columns" = "id", "partition_type" = "DAY" },
    "raw_incident_information"  = { "business_key_columns" = "id", "partition_type" = "DAY" }
  }
}


module "daily_closing_balance" {
  source           = "../append_only_history_bq_tables"
  gcp_project      = var.gcp_project
  bq_location      = var.bq_location
  dataset_id       = google_bigquery_dataset.dwh_core_dataset.dataset_id
  module_base_path = path.module
  use_source_ord   = false
  from_dwh_core    = true

  tables = {
    "daily_closing_balance"    = { "business_key_columns" = "full_date,account_number,customer_id", "partition_type" = "DAY" }
  }
  depends_on = [google_bigquery_dataset.dwh_core_dataset]
}
```

The **append_only_history_bq_tables** contains this resource

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "dwh_core_snapshot_daily" {
  for_each = var.tables
  dataset_id = var.dataset_id
  project = var.gcp_project
  table_id = "${each.key}_snapshot_current_daily"
  schema = file("${local.schema_def_folder}/${each.key}.json")
  deletion_protection=false
}
```

How to conditionally call the **dwh_core_snapshot_daily** resource only if the **from_dwh_core** variable is set to **true**?

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Conditional Expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/conditionals.html):

```
resource "google_bigquery_table" "dwh_core_snapshot_daily" {

  for_each = var.from_dwh_core == true ? var.tables : {}

  dataset_id = var.dataset_id
  project = var.gcp_project
  table_id = "${each.key}_snapshot_current_daily"
  schema = file("${local.schema_def_folder}/${each.key}.json")
  deletion_protection=false
}
```

Comment: I also think about this method. But by calling it from for_each, will it effect the arguments below it (the table_id and schema)? It will cause calling a null values when we call each.key right?

Comment: @RanggaPutraPertama  No, because there is no elements in the map. The map `{}` is empty.

Comment: @RanggaPutraPertama No problem. If you test it and it works, acceptance of the answer would be appreciated.